# How to do aritmethic operations with django queries and .count?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to get a value by using the amount of objects I have in my database and making operations over that and then displaying the result in the template (So I'm passing this value in the context). The answers I found was about making operations with model fields, and that doesn't help me.

This is what I tried to do in the view. (status is a charfield with options, but it could be anything)

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Index, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    amount_one = mymodel.objects.filter(status='status1').count
    amount_two = mymodel.objects.filter(status='status2').count

    total_amount = amount_one + amount_two
    result_amount = (amount_one * 100) // total_amount

    context['result'] = result_amount

    return context
```

This doesn't work, but you could get the idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.count()` instead of `.count`.

Or you can use `aggregate` and `Count`:

```
status1 = Count('status', filter=Q(status='status1'))
status2 = Count('status', filter=Q(status='status2'))
total_amount = sum(mymodel.objects.aggregate(status1=status1, status2=status2).values())
```

Or the simplest:

```
total_amount = mymodel.objects.filter(status__in=['status1', 'status2']).count()
```

Comment: Yeah it should be giving you `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'method'`

Comment: What result do you get with adding `.count`?

Comment: That was the error I was getting. Changing .count for .count() worked! Ty.
The `status__in` don't work for me, it says `status__in is not defined`

Comment: Right i got a typo. It should be `status__in=['status1', 'status2']`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

use method **count()**  .you missed  brackets.

```
amount_one = mymodel.objects.filter(status='status1').count()
```